# use Swagger in dot net core api framework 2

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

How to use Swagger in asp.net core API.
i used core framework-2.
i try

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

package, but it's not supported in framework-2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and could be able to fix it by installing  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` Nuget package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
```

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/438